# Android Linear Timeline Project

Tags: android, github, android-view, timeline, android-videoview

I'm search on free project (Git etc) that create a linear timeline chooser for video or similar view.

its look like this:
[image]

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dm8Zt1ps9P8
you can refer that and source code available https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-timeline/

Comment: Thanks friend! @Rahul